# Use the cookies stored by the browser to make a HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

For example, if I make an `HttpWebRequest` to "www.sport.com", I would like to use cookies that the browser has already stored in previous sessions. How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**
Perhaps I did not explain well, if I make a httpwebreqeust to "www.google.com" the request.CookieContainer must contain all the cookies that chrome / firefox / ie / etc ... have stored in all previous sessions for google.com. for example in firefox I can see them going into options> privacy> remove single cookie.

**UPDATE2:**
i need something like this:

in javascript if i create a httpwebrequest like this

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com"><\/script>')
```

automatically takes the cookies already stored in previous sessions of the browser

Comment: I don't know how to populate the request.CookieContainer with the already stored cookies in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First create HttpWebRequest, set everything and then to add cookies to it, follow as this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) says:

1) Create a System.Net.CookieContainer object for the HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer property of the HttpWebRequest.

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

2) Add cookie objects to the HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer by using the CookieContainer.Add method.

```
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://api.search.live.net"),new Cookie("id","1234"));
```

**UPDATE:** For your new comment, accessing cookies is pretty simple, you can get them from HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.

Comment: thank you gaurav but i don't need to set manually the cookies. i need to populate the request.CookieContainer with the already stored cookies in the browser (for example chrome)

Comment: Try something like: 'request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); request.CookieContainer.Add(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies);'

Comment: unfortunately seems to not work, it gives me only as a cookie ASP.NET_SessionId. but if I make the request directly browsing with chrome, for example if I go to google.com there are so many cookies

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain well, if I make a httpwebreqeust to "www.google.com" the request.CookieContainer must contain all the cookies that chrome / firefox / ie / etc ... have stored in all previous sessions. for example in firefox I can see them going into options> privacy> remove single cookie.

Comment: Microsoft made a Cookie cookie type for HttpWebRequest (outgoing request) and an HttpCookie type for HttpRequestBase (incoming request). They made all the types incompatible, so you can't copy cookies between collections. That's beyond stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that uses HttpWebRequest with browser cookies available via the HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies object.

```
public static string WebRequestPostRequest(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpCookieCollection httpCookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies;

    for (int j = 0; j < httpCookies.Count; j++)
    {
        HttpCookie httpCookie = httpCookies.Get(j);
        Cookie myCookie = new Cookie();

        // Convert between the System.Net.Cookie to a System.Web.HttpCookie...
        myCookie.Domain = request.RequestUri.Host;
        myCookie.Expires = httpCookie.Expires;
        myCookie.Name = httpCookie.Name;
        myCookie.Path = httpCookie.Path;
        myCookie.Secure = httpCookie.Secure;
        myCookie.Value = httpCookie.Value;

        cookieContainer.Add(myCookie);
    }

    request.Method = "POST";
    //set other request properties here...

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: You forgot `myCookie.HttpOnly = httpCookie.HttpOnly;`. It prevents a cookie from being accessed by a client-side script, but doesn't prevent it from being transferred to or from the server.